# How to override using two for() to compare two columns from different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I have two dataframes with address information:

```
      import pandas as pd
      from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
      from fuzzywuzzy import process

      df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'countries': ['PORTUGAL', 'PORTUGAL', 'BRASIL', 'ESPANHA', 
                                         'PARIS'],                   
                           'number': [1,2,3,4,5],
                           'address_description':['ESPLANADA DOM CARLOS',
                                                  'AVENIDA BRASILIA',
                                                  'PARQUE NACIONAL DA TIJUCA',
                                                  'C D ARISTIDES MAILLOL',
                                                  'CHAMP DE MARS 5 AV ANATOLE']})

      print(df_1)
      # Output:
                    countries   number  address_description
                    PORTUGAL     1      ESPLANADA DOM CARLOS
                    PORTUGAL     2      AVENIDA BRASILIA
                    BRASIL       3      PARQUE NACIONAL DA TIJUCA
                    ESPANHA      4      C D ARISTIDES MAILLOL
                    PARIS        5      CHAMP DE MARS 5 AV ANATOLE

      df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'countries': ['BRASIL', 'BRASIL', 'PORTUGAL'],                   
                           'number': [1,2,3],
                           'address':['PQ NACIONAL TIJUCA', 'URCA', 'ESPLANADAA DOM CARLO']})

      print(df_2)
      # Output:
                countries   number  address
                 BRASIL        1    PQ NACIONAL TIJUCA
                 BRASIL        2    URCA
                 PORTUGAL      3    ESPLANADAA DOM CARLO
```

I need to create two new columns in 'df_2'. One column to receive the fuzzy value of the comparison of the address strings and the other to receive the address of 'df_1' which is similar to the address of 'df_2'. This assignment will only happen if the fuzzy result is greater than 80.
I made the following code:

```
      df_2['New_column_1'] = None
      df_2['New_column_2'] = 0

      for i in range(0, len(df_1)):
          for j in range(0, len(df_2)):
    
              # Checks countries
              if(df_1['countries'].iloc[i] == df_2['countries'].iloc[j]):
        
                  var_adress_df1 = df_1['address_description'].iloc[i]
                  var_adress_df2 = df_2['address'].iloc[j]
        
                  var_value_fuzzy = fuzz.ratio(var_adress_df1, var_adress_df2)
        
                  #print(var_adress_df1)
                  #print(var_adress_df2)
                  #print(var_value_fuzzy)
                  #print("\n")
        
                  if(var_value_fuzzy > 80):
                      df_2['New_column_1'].loc[j] = df_1['address_description'].iloc[i]
                      df_2['New_column_2'].loc[j] = var_value_fuzzy
```

The code above works perfectly! returns the following output:

```
      print(df_2)
      # Output:
          countries number  address               New_column_1                New_column_2
          BRASIL      1     PQ NACIONAL TIJUCA    PARQUE NACIONAL DA TIJUCA       84
          BRASIL      2     URCA                  None                             0
          PORTUGAL    3     ESPLANADAA DOM CARLO  ESPLANADA DOM CARLOS            95
```

However, I needed to use two for() commands. Is there a way to override the for() and keep the same output?

Note: To install the fuzzywuzzy library use: pip install fuzzywuzzy

Comment: Normally you would use `.join()`

Comment: Do you know what the code would look like with .join()?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really a pandas user. Google "pandas join tutorial"

Comment: Show what you tried, we're not going to write it for you. There are hundreds of SO questions about joining dataframes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming. I have a hard time understanding the use of functions with apply(), join() and merge()

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a tutoring service, you're expected to learn programming on your own.